# why is this script not working on my site

Tags: themes

I found a script so I can take care that on some months I can change the number of post at a page.

So I implment this script at this way : http://pastebin.com/Nbqy0KBU

But still all articles are displayed as you can see here : http://test.tamarawobben.nl/2005/04

Anyone a idea why and how to solve this ?

Roelof

Edit 1 :

What I want to achieve is this in pseudo code.

When the year is 2005 and the month april(04) and we are on the first page of that month then 1 article must be displayed. if not then the standard number of articles must be displayed.

Comment: Can you explain what's the significance of the year and month in this? The 'page' I can understand, but year and month? How flexible are you looking for this solution to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this option of achieving what you seem to be requiring:

```
function wpse31701_filter_query() {
    global $wp_query;
    // Check year and month
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'year' ) == 2005 and $wp_query->get( 'monthnum' ) == 5 )
        // Check page number to apply offset
        if ( $wp_query->get( 'paged') > 1 ) $wp_query->set( 'offset', 1 );
        else $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse31701_filter_query' );
```

Here we alter the query as soon as `$the_query` is ready to get the posts, to modify the `posts_per_page` to 1 if `paged` is 1, and apply and offset of 1 post if `paged` is > 1.

The important thing is to apply `offset` and `posts_per_page`; the rest is purely conditional so apply to taste.

Comment: Oke, and to test this I have to put it into functions.php ?

Comment: Theoretically - yes.

Comment: I changed the action hook to `pre_get_posts` instead, it's a more suitable hook; things happen after `parse_request`...

Comment: Oke, Can I also change the sort order so the oldest article get displayed first.

Comment: Sorry, I see a problem now. the frontpage is now showing all the articles but not the frontpage message. Can the script causes this ?

Comment: Yes, you can reverse using the same methods, and if you're going to reverse back (normal order for pages > 1) you don't need the offset (the post will be displayed as the very last on on the last page).

Comment: As for the problem - depends on how you implemented the script, check the conditions - make them match only to what you need. You said year 2005 and monthnum 5 - that's what my code does, if you modified it check the conditions. Try to remove the script and see if it's causing your problem. As it is in my answer - it should not cause a problem. What's the error message that you're getting?

Comment: Hello, I found it. It was a try from me to get the articles in the right order. But I still get it completly. Can I do something like this $(wp_query -> set ('posts_per_page', '1') && sortorder=ASC

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters has got all the information you require to build you custom queries. In your case `$wp_query->set('orderby', 'date'); $wp_query->set('order', 'DESC');`

Comment: Oke, So there will be two query->set. One for the articles and one for the sorting. Do I understand this right

Comment: Yes, you can have as many of them as you require. If you want 2 or more `orderby` rules, you separate them with a space like so: `$wp_query->set('orderby', 'date author'); $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC DESC');` (an useless example).

Comment: oke, then this discussion can be closed. see http://test.tamarawobben.nl

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Close the question by accepting an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`is_category();` is checking if you're on a category archive or not. So, `is_category('1perpage');` will only return true when you're on http://test.tamarawobben.nl/category/1perpage/

Comment: oke, Bad way to go.

Comment: Find another way to achieve what I want. To put 1 articles on the first page of that month and the rest on the second page of that ,month

Comment: You may be able to achieve the same thing using sticky posts - but I haven't worked with them enough to know all the ramifications of marking a post as sticky.

Comment: Could I use if_year=2005 and if_month=04 and if_paged() ??

Comment: Probably - but do you want the entire date archive to show up with one entry per page - or just the first page to show up? You may want to go back and modify your initial question (i.e. what are you trying to achieve?), so we can help find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there are any template tags to achieve what you want, so you're stuck comparing the query string (try `get_query_var(query_vars)`) to `200504`

From the `$WP_Query` object: `... [query_vars] => Array ( [m] => 201110 ...`

If it's a match, you have a multitude of options... I might try an if/then bracket... psuedo code:

```
 if ($queryvar == '200504' && $paged == 1):
    $singlepost = get_post(...);
    // write display code for your singleton post.
 else:
    query_posts($query_string.'&offset=1');
    //run through the normal loop code here
 endif;
```

This is still likely to mess with paging, which is the sticky wicket here... I'm sure someone else can come up with a better answer, but maybe that'll get you started.